# Manga where MC is kicked out of the party, kills a random monster, and becomes a dragonkin with level 300

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character is kicked out of the hero's party and then he kills a random monster and he becomes a dragonkin with level 300. He then gets a traveling companion, and the companion shows him the way to a legendary sword. He completely destroys a labyrinth/dungeon — when the hero tries to challenge the labyrinth/dungeon, it's not even there. The main character gets recruited by the noble in that city. The hero has s*x with the other 3 female members of his party using a skill, doing it when the mc is looking away, on the pretext of going to take a piss.

It's not *I've been killing slime for 300 years and maxed out my level*.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?

Answer (score 6):

This seems to strongly match [**A Warrior Exiled by the Hero and His Lover**](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/a-warrior-exiled-by-the-hero-and-his-lover/). Looks like it was originally a novel, but a manga adaptation also exists.

The first chapter has the MC - named Toru Eiban - being kicked out of the party and his childhood friend "hero" supposedly sleeping with their 3 female companions (including MC's fiance).

He then kills a black demon dog to vent his frustration and gets a ton of EXP from his ability *The Saving System* (that was useless so far). He hits level 300 and his body is transformed into that of a dragonkin/dragon man. He goes to a town and buys a companion from a market (because of trust issues).

I haven't confirmed your other points about the legendary sword, but the synopsis does mention that the hero's party falls into decline because of lack of work.

Comment: Chapter 2 has the legendary sword, "The Sacred Arms".