# Manga where the main character is kicked out of a party and meets a cat/fox girl

Tags: story-identification, manga

The story of the manga goes as follows:

In a fantasy world, the main character (MC) is in a party consisting of the hero and three girls, one of which is the MC's fiancée. The MC has his skills/abilities locked and the experience gained fills ups a bar, but he is not able to level up. The hero hypnotizes the three girls and they kick the MC out.

After being kicked out, the MC is wandering fighting some monsters, during which the accumulated experience crosses threshold and the abilities get unlocked; now the mc is level 300 or 500. He then kills a dragon on the way to the nearest town and again levels up.

In the next town, he buys a cat/fox slave, who is sick, and takes her to a doctor to heal her. He gives the dragon's blood/heart to the doctor to make medicine with and heals her.

A night after, the fox girl turns into a beauty and they both clear a dungeon in the city.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? And do you recall the hair colour of the cat/fox girl?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Other "can't level up" stories can be found at https://www.aniculmedia.com/2022/07/manga-where-main-character-is-stuck-being-level-1.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Manga where MC is kicked out of the party, kills a random monster, and becomes a dragonkin with level 300](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/259904/manga-where-mc-is-kicked-out-of-the-party-kills-a-random-monster-and-becomes-a), *[A Warrior Exiled by the Hero and His Lover](https://myanimelist.net/manga/143923/Keikenchi_Chochiku_de_Nonbiri_Shoushin_Ryokou__Yuusha_to_Koibito_ni_Tsuihou_sareta_Senshi_no_Mujikaku_Zamaa)*, aka *Keikenchi Chochiku de Nonbiri Shoushin Ryokou: Yuusha to Koibito ni Tsuihou sareta Senshi no Mujikaku Zamaa*.

[image: Front cover of Keikenchi Chochiku de Nonbiri Shoushin Ryokou: Yuusha to Koibito ni Tsuihou sareta Senshi no Mujikaku Zamaa]

> After losing his girlfriend to a brave hero, Toru is expelled from his S-Rank party. With a feeling of sadness and pain in his heart, he defeats a demon he meets outside the city, and his ability [to save experience] is broken! Toru becomes level 300 in the blink of an eye!
>
> With this power that far surpasses that of heroes, there is nothing that can stop him. Kaede, a slave he met on his journey, forms a group called the “Mangyu Brigade”, and easily completes dungeons, acquires the legendary sacred weapons, and thanks to his skills, his friends level up easily!
>
> He rescued a countess who was attacked by bandits on the road, and befriended a legendary beast. Oru’s journey continues at a leisurely pace, as he repeatedly encounters various people along the way, while his former party of heroes are deprived of opportunities to play an active role and fall into decline. This is the beginning of the life of a 300 level warrior!

Found with a search for `manga hero can't level until he hits threshold kills dragon`